# jQuery get the first next element in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML form with two DOM elements that work together - input and error message. When the form is submitted and the input is empty, I want to apply some code to the error message. My problem is that my HTML for the position of the error message is constructed differently based on the platform - desktop or mobile - and I cannot do anything about it.

Example desktop:

```
<form name="form">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="input-one">
        <div class="error-message"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="input-two">
        <div class="error-message"></div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Example mobile:

```
<form name="form">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="input-one">
    </div>
    <div class="error-message"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="input-two">
    </div>
    <div class="error-message"></div>
    ...
</form>
```

You can see, that based on the platform, the error message can be part of the same or a different parent. For that reason I cannot use jQuery's .next() selector. I tried using also .closest() selector, but that transfers the DOM upwards and also doesn't work.

So what I am trying to achieve is - with a relative reference of a DOM element (in this case input), find the first following DOM element containing a specific class (in this case "error-message").

Example Javascript stub:

```
$('[name=form]').find(':text:visible').each(function (i, el) {
// select the next error message
});
```

Is there any combination of selectors that can help me achieve this?

Comment: How are you checking for empty? Post your JavaScript please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate that this couldn't have been handled with CSS, but if you're really stuck with that structure, then assuming `$input` is a jQuery object for the `input` element, then:

```
const $error = $input.nextAll(".error-message").add($input.parent().next(".error-message"));
```

[`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) will select all following siblings that match the selector. `parent` will go up to the parent, and `next` will match the following sibling, but only if it matches the selector. Since one or the other of those will be empty, you'll end up with a set of one element — the error message element.

Desktop:

```js
$("input").on("input", function() {
    const $input = $(this);
    const $error = $input.nextAll(".error-message").add($input.parent().next(".error-message"));
    $error.text("Count: " + $input.val().length);
});
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="input-one">
        <div class="error-message"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="input-two">
        <div class="error-message"></div>
    </div>
    Type in either input to see a count in its error box.
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Mobile:

```js
$("input").on("input", function() {
    const $input = $(this);
    const $error = $input.nextAll(".error-message").add($input.parent().next(".error-message"));
    $error.text("Count: " + $input.val().length);
});
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="input-one">
    </div>
    <div class="error-message"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="input-two">
    </div>
    <div class="error-message"></div>
    Type in either input to see a count in its error box.
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Essentially, this is a neat, shortened version of `error = input.nextAll(".error-message"); if (error.length === 0) error = input.parent().next(".error-message")`

Comment: @freedomn-m - Exactly. And that version might well make for something more maintainable, tbh. :-)